# SQLite Database is not working after standalone build in Unity3D

Tags: database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a Standalone Application using SQLite in Unity3D,
I am getting a strange problem. 
I created a database using sqliteadmin, and created a Table named Admin, having field: id, email, password.

I am able to Login using email and password but in Unity Edit Mode.

Its working fine but when i build it and then run it, its not working, I have no idea why?

[Reference](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html)

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using System.Data;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DatabaseConnection : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text em;
    public Text pas;
    public static int id;
    public static string email ="";
    public static string password="";
    public static string wrong="Wrong Email/Password !!!";
    public Text Wrong;
    public GameObject loading;
    private ButtonsController bc;
    public GameObject loginPanel;

    void Start () {

        string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/Database/TMDB.s3db";
        IDbConnection dbconn;
        dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection (conn);
        dbconn.Open ();
        IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand ();
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT id, email, password " + "FROM Admin";
        dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader ();
        while (reader.Read()) {
             id = reader.GetInt32 (0);
             email = reader.GetString(1);
             password = reader.GetString(2);

        }
        reader.Close ();
        reader = null;
        dbcmd.Dispose ();
        dbcmd = null;
        dbconn.Close ();
        dbconn = null;
        loading.SetActive (false);
    }

    public void login()
    {
        if ((em.text == email) && (pas.text == password)) {
            Debug.Log ("Success");
            loading.SetActive (true);
            loginPanel.SetActive(false);
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Error");
            Wrong.text = wrong.ToString ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to do a Debug.log on your filePath, and see if it is getting the correct path.

Comment: Which filepath? you mean Database file path?

Comment: Yep.. The "conn" string

Comment: yes, file path is correct, output is: URI=file:E:/Unity3D/TM Library Management/Assets/Database/TMDB.s3db

Comment: I am guessing you did that in the Unity Editor itself. Try doing it in your standalone build. You could display the conn string on your screen in a Unity UI Text. Also, What is the problem you are facing? Are you getting an error or the connection is not being established at all?

Comment: you are right, path is not showing after build. but working in Editor Mode. Why?

Comment: i think login() is not working. @AnmolMahatpurkar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124241/discussion-between-anmol-mahatpurkar-and-jamshaid-alam).

Answer (score 0):

Application.datapath is readonly.

What you need is Application.persistentDataPath

Checkout this link

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/209108/when-to-use-persistentdatapath-versus-datapath.html

Comment: After replacing  Application.persistentDataPath, its giving error SqliteException: Unable to open the database file

Comment: you need to write this ( TMDB.s3db ) first before you try to access it,
Please create this database in whatever path you want and then try to access it. you have tons of tutorial for this....

Comment: which device are you trying ?

Comment: Standalone PC build

Comment: have a look at this, This is for Android, but it will work for most platforms for sure 

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/956876/copy-sqlite-database-from-assets-folder-to-android.html

Comment: I think, login() is not working as expected, because im closing DB connection in start() i created public login() to work with UI button, i need to call db connection in login(), but i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create **StreamingAssets** folder into your **Assets**, and use this connection string:

```
string conn = "URI=file:" +
    System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Database/TMDB.s3db");
```

Using streaming asset is necessary, it places files into the normal filesystem on the target machine to make them accessible via a pathname.

More info:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html

Answer (score 0):

dude ,,, just check the files bro,,, after building the database is empty so go and replace the database file with the one u been working on with the same database name .